# how to display bootstrap success message in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Hi Friend's need help how to display success message in laravel 5.1, I have applied  it is working but twice display what is the reason . this is my layout.balde.php code

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
<div class="alert-success" id="popup_notification">
    <strong>{!! trans('main.message') !!}</strong>{{ session('success') }}
</div>
```

@endif
this is my controller page code:

```
  return Redirect::route($this->cdroute, array($customer_id))->with('success',trans($this->updatemsg));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//in controller
    return Redirect::route($this->cdroute, array($customer_id))->with('success',trans($this->updatemsg));

//in blade template
    @if (session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller page code:

```
Session::flash('success',trans($this->updatemsg));
Redirect::route($this->cdroute, array($customer_id));
```

layout.balde.php code

```
@if ( Session::has('success') )
   <div class="alert-success" id="popup_notification">
     {{ Session::get('success') }}
  </div>      
@endif
```

Comment: Sir are you understand my question , the flash message displayed fine, but  when I insert a record after that two time displayed, that is my question

Comment: I think another place I called so that is the reason displayed two time

Comment: but  when I update the record I just called in my controller page Session::flash('success',trans($this->updatemsg));
Redirect::route($this->cdroute, array($customer_id));

Comment: Ok. please confirm that you called {{ session('success') }} only once in your view page. <div class="alert-success" id="popup_notification">
    <strong>{!! trans('main.message') !!}</strong> only here {{ session('success') }}
</div>

Comment: attach "only here" with above code as shown in above comment. and check if it repeats the "only here" message.

Comment: <div class="alert-success succ" id="popup_notification">
        <strong>{!! trans('main.message') !!}</strong> test
    </div>

Comment: but same problem two time displayed message for Message:test

Comment: I have used only two page one is layout.balde.php and another one is controller

Comment: layout code:@if (session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert-success succ" id="popup_notification">
        <strong>{!! trans('main.message') !!}</strong>{{ session('success') }}
    </div>
 @endif

Comment: $request->session()->flash('success', 'New customer update successfully.');
        return Redirect::route($this->cdroute, array($customer_id));

Comment: which is the page you are redirecting to? eturn Redirect::route($this->cdroute     @sivakumar.s

Comment: protected $cdroute = 'main.customerdep.order';

Comment: return Redirect::route($this->cdroute, array($customer_id))->with('success',trans($this->updatemsg));

Comment: can I view the main.customerdep.order (.blade.php) page in which you have extended @extends('layout')

Comment: no that is not a issue because just now I removed ,but same problem

Comment: this is my code  return Redirect::back()->with('success',trans($this->updatemsg));